# Dispatch maps for across platforms

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm defining a new "BSTR PreviewName" with in the '.odl' file.The dispatch map in the corresponding '.cpp' is:

```
    DISP_PROPERTY_EX(CDB,"PreviewName", GetPreviewName, SetPreviewName, VT_BSTR);
```

The corresponding GetPreviewName() is:

```
    BSTR  CDB::GetPreviewName() 
    {
    return m_name;
    }
```

The corresponding SetPreviewName() is:

```
    void CDB::SetPreviewName(BSTR newValue) 
    {
    refresh();
    }
```

I'm trying to access the value of "PreviewName" across platforms.
The "PreviewName" is never being set to the value that is being returned from GetPreviewName().
Are there any additional settings etc that I'm missing on to access "PreviewName" across platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Your setter doesn't appear to do anything with the new value.

```
void CDB::SetPreviewName(BSTR newValue) 
{
    m_name = newValue; //add this line?
    refresh();
}
```

Comment: add PreviewName to classwizard in vs2010.